# Rails 3 Ajax Cannot get newly created record to append at bottom of existing table

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

On my index page I return a table of query results using Ajax.  I having successfully created a new record using Ajax too.  My problem is trying to get that new record immediately appended to the table of query results.  I have seen Railscast 136 and cannot get it to work, maybe because I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.

Here is my index method, from the lookup controller that returns the initial results

```
 def index
    @lookuprows = Lookup.return_lookup_rows(:pubyear, :codetype)

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
    end
 end
```

Here is the index.js.erb ( I did get this from Railscast 136, except Ryan had ***"<%= j render(@lookuprows) %>"***.  I could not get this to work.  I kept on getting a missing partial error.  The only way I could get it to work is by making a _lkupshow.html.erb partial).

```
 $("#lkupresultarea").html("<%= j render("lkupshow") %>
```

I have the ajax select working, here is some of the code from lkupshow partial that displays the records

```
 <table class="lkupdata">
    <tbody class="lkuptbody">
       <% @lookuprows.each do |lkup| %>
         <tr>
           <td><input value="<%= lkup.codevalue %>" /></td>
           <td><input value="<%= lkup.parameters %>" /></td>
           <td><input value="<%= lkup.remark %>" /></td>
         </tr>
       <% end %>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

In the same partial, I have a form above it

```
 <div class="lkupnewdiv">
    <%= form_tag(lkupcreate_path, :remote => "true") do %>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td><%= text_field(:lookup, :codevalue) %></td>
           <td><%= text_field(:lookup, :parameters) %></td>
           <td><%= text_field(:lookup, :remark) %></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td><%= submit_tag("Submit", :id=> "lkupsubmit") %></td></tr>
       </table>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

Here is the create method from the Lookup controller, the save works

```
 def create
   @lookup = Lookup.new
   @lookup.codevalue = params[:lookup][:codevalue]
   @lookup.parameters = params[:lookup][:parameters]
   @lookup.remark = params[:lookup][:remark]
   @lookup.save

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
   end
 end
```

And finally, here is the create.js.erb, i get the same "missing partial" error here too.

```
 $(".lkupnewdiv").hide();
 $(".lkupdata > tbody:last").append('<%= j render(@lookup) %>');
```

So when I add my new record it does save, but there's nothing to indicate that from the form in the browser.  Could I maybe change my create method to this?

```
 def create
   @lookup = Lookup.new
   @lookup.codevalue = params[:lookup][:codevalue]
   @lookup.parameters = params[:lookup][:parameters]
   @lookup.remark = params[:lookup][:remark]
   @lookup.save

   # Call the whole query again?  pubyear is one of the variables, just didnt feel like
   # typing them all in
   @lookuprows = Lookup.return_lookup_rows(:pubyear, :codetype)

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      # Shouldnt the @lookuprows be accessible with the path below?
      format.js { redirect_to lkupshow_path }
   end
 end
```

Since I cannot get past the "missing partial" error from the create.js.erb, I am looking for other solutions.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You confused the question. Make it short... Where is your index.html.erb?

Comment: @Vinay my index.html.erb is a form with a collection select and a grouped collection select.  In the index page, I also have a div tag id=lkupresultarea, that the index.js.erb renders the partial, _lkupshow, into.